# Yank to register on Qt Creator FakeVim, depends on keyboard?

Tags: qt, vim, qt-creator, vi, macvim

To yank a word to register `a` on Vim (on macOS) I do

```
control+viw "ay
```

I tried the same on Qt Creator FakeVim, I can go to FakeVim mode by `control+shift+v, control+shift+v`. But it goes until the point I can select a word, but produces a `ä` instead of allowing me to yank to register `a`.

Is this behavior only here? Am I doing something wrong?

The above was achieved using `Brazilian Pro` keyboard.

For reference:

- https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-editor-fakevim.html
- https://www.brianstorti.com/vim-registers/

Comment: Not sure what you're doing with ctrl-v there. I tried yanking a word the classical way with `"ayiw`, then pasting it with `"ap`, and it worked in my fakevim.

Comment: Does your approach work using non `U.S.` keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

*(Note: I don't have enough reputation for a comment yet.)*

I can confirm the behavior for QtCreator 4.11.0 in FakeVim mode. Your issue is that you're using an international keyboard layout. The keystroke `"a` (one after the other) produces the Umlaut `ä`. This also applies to normal vim and any text input method; it's your keyboard layout, after all.

To actually type a `"` you have to press `"<SPACE>` (one after the other). So to yank into register a, it would be `"<SPACE>a` (one by one). This works in normal vim for me but unfortunately not in the QtCreator FakeVim. I believe it's a bug in Qt's FakeVim implementation.